# Creating a 2 dimensional jagged array of undetermined size

Tags: java, arrays, jagged-arrays

For my program, i am making a 2D jagged array of integers and the length of each array inside depends on the input of the user.

Lets say for something like:

```
int seq [] [] = new int [M] [];
for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
    seq[i] = new int [N[i]];
```

The total number of arrays (M) and the N array with length for each array depends on the input by user.
Is there a way i can make this so the resultant 2D array can be used by any method inside the class?

Thanks.

Comment: make it an instance variable of the class and then every method in that class will be able to use that

Comment: What exactly is the problem? `seq.length` and `seq[i].length` with `0 <= i < M` should be enough to **not** violate any boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it array an instance variable and initialize it in some init method or constructor.

```
public class Test{
    int[][] array;

    public void initialize() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m = scanner.nextInt();
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        array = new int[m][n];
    }

     public void processArray() {
       if(array != null) {
         //process array
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: That's not a jagged array.

Comment: That's just an example of course. For each m elements you can get separate inputs and create array of that size.

Comment: This was very helpful. I can extract the length needed for each array from the input. Shouldn't be hard now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> Yes it is Possible you Take The Size of the Rows and Columns of the Array at run time then Create the Array According to the Size you Provide.

```
 int m;
 int n;
System.out.println("EnTer size of Row and column");
m = input.nextInt();
n = input.nextInt();
int[] arr = new int[m][n];
```

Comment: That's not a jagged array.